# Наследование С++

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, наследование, множественное-наследование

Требуется организовать множественное наследование на языке С++ по данной схеме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, о своих идеях, как это можно реализовать, покажите попытки это сделать, опишите конкретные проблемы и задайте конкретные вопросы

Comment: 1. Плохое оформление вопроса. 2. при чем тут множественное наследование? 3. Собственно, на картинке у вас и ответ.

Comment: на вашем рисунке нет множественного наследования, везде обычное (от одного класса)

Comment: @user231812  Смысл вопроса не ясен.

Answer (score 4):

```
class A {};
class B: public A {};
class C: public A {};
class D: public C {};
class E: public C {};
class F: public E {};
class G: public D {};
class H: public A {};
```

как сказали, множественного наследования тут нет.